# How can i take Values from a JSON array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, key-value-store

How can i take  "**steamid**" from array **friends**? 
What i`m doing wrong?
**friendslist** and **friends** really confused me.

```js
var obj = 
{
 "friendslist": {
  "friends": [
   {
    "steamid": "76561197965254644",
    "relationship": "friend",
    "friend_since": 1427418915
   },
   {
    "steamid": "76561197967483523",
    "relationship": "friend",
    "friend_since": 1483547216
   },
   {
    "steamid": "76561197967658405",
    "relationship": "friend",
    "friend_since": 1431204923
   }
      ]
 }
}
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  console.log(obj[i].friends['steamid']);
   
}
```

Comment: obj.friendslist.friends[0].steamid

Comment: `obj` is not an array which you could iterate using `for`. It is an object. `friends` is an array.

Comment: @KD Wow Thanks is working but can you explain me why this is working?

Comment: @ShadowGR please find my answer with answer to your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you requested explanation in your comment for my answer...

You have a JSON object which holds certain properties which could be another object, a `String`/`Number`/`Date` or an `Array`. Hence to access a property inside your object you have to first access its child directly by its name in a following way.

```
obj.friendslist
```

OR

```
obj["friendslist"]
```

You have another child inside the `friendslist` hence you have to access it in following way:

```
obj.friendslist.friends
```

Now your `friends` property holds an array, you can iterate through it using a `for loop`

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.friendslist.friends.length; i++) {
  console.log(obj.friendslist.friends[i]['steamid']);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
 var obj = 
    {
     "friendslist": {
      "friends": [
       {
        "steamid": "76561197965254644",
        "relationship": "friend",
        "friend_since": 1427418915
       },
       {
        "steamid": "76561197967483523",
        "relationship": "friend",
        "friend_since": 1483547216
       },
       {
        "steamid": "76561197967658405",
        "relationship": "friend",
        "friend_since": 1431204923
       }
          ]
     }
    }
    obj.friendslist.friends.forEach((i) => {
      console.log(i.steamid);
    })
```

`obj.friendslist.friends` returns the array and that can then be looped over. Each value in the array is an object and the property you need is the steamid.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: .forEach is better than a simple for loop?

Comment: Thanks @bahrep, made necessary changes. That was actually my first post, I'm still kind of a newbie

Answer (score 0):

Get friendlist object then get friends array/list and iterate over it.
For every object in it, print steamid or whatever is in the object.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < obj.friendslist.friends.length ; i++) {
      console.log(obj.friendslist.friends[i].steamid );
 }
```

Comment: Thank you,now makes sense in my head !

Comment: @jonhid, code only answers aren't very useful. Try to expand a bit on your answer.

Comment: You are right but it was so obvious that I thought it was self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

You need first to acces to the nested *friends* property and then to itterate through it.

```
var friends = obj.friendslist.friends;

for (var i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {
   console.log(friends[i]['steamid']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Array [**map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to iterate the array of objects for getting specific key value.

The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

**Working demo :**

```js
var obj = 
{
 "friendslist": {
  "friends": [
   {
    "steamid": "76561197965254644",
    "relationship": "friend",
    "friend_since": 1427418915
   },
   {
    "steamid": "76561197967483523",
    "relationship": "friend",
    "friend_since": 1483547216
   },
   {
    "steamid": "76561197967658405",
    "relationship": "friend",
    "friend_since": 1431204923
   }
      ]
 }
};

var newObj = obj.friendslist.friends.map(function(item) {
    return item.steamid;
});

console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: i think i can do this with  : newObj.push(obj.friendslist.friends.steamid) ,
or is better to do it with map?

Comment: map will iterate the each element of array. your newObj.push(obj.friendslist.friends.steamid) will not do that..and map is a better way to iterate the array instead of for loop.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a `Object`, with a `friendslist` property. 
That property is also a `Object` with only one property, `friends`.
`friends` is a `Array` of `Object`.
Thoses object have the property `steamid` you are interested in.

However, your code try to iterate `obj` directly, instead of the `friendslist` property. This work because accessing a property can be done the same way as accessing a element of a array:

```
obj.property === obj['property']
```

So you are trying to access the property `0` of `obj`. As you can see, it doesn't exist, and return `undefined`.

What you want is to iterate the `friendslist` property:

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    console.log(
        obj. //The base object
        friendslist. //The friendslist property
        friends[i]. //The friends property, iterated
        steamid //Get the steamid
    );
}
```

Alternatives could use the generic `map` or `forEach` method of `Array` on `obj.friendslist.friends`, which can also be written as `obj['friendslist']['friends']`.

You may want to read about the similarities between `Array` and `Object` in javascript, and their respectives method. MDN is a good place for that, but any documentation should suffice.